# Enumeration of ordinal numbers

Tags: punctuation, numbers

I would like to convey the following:

> Please, read the first, the sixth and the tenth page.

What is a correct written version?

> Please, read the 1st, 6th and 10th page.
>
> Please, read the pages 1, 6 and 10.

Or both are wrong? Please, comment also on the punctuation, namely should I add comma after "Please" and before "and".

**UPD** Would the answer change if I would like to omit "and":

> Please, read the 1st, 6th, 10th page.

Comment: Switching from lexical to arithmetic notation doesn't affect the *ordinal/cardinal* choice. Personally, I think ordinals sound awkward with such a disparate list, and using words rather than digits would soon start to look really clumsy if you need to identify pages nearer the end of a book, even if expressed as cardinals. So bearing in mind that *next* week you might need to get the class to ***read pages 98, 107 and 121***, I'd suggest you start out using that notation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is common to refer to the *first page* or *last page* but not usually other pages by ordinal. It is more usual to refer to *page 10*.

I would omit the comma and the definite article, but not *and*, so I would write

> Please read pages 1, 6 and 10.

However suppose you are exasperated by a student's persistent questions, you might add the comma for emphasis.

> Please, read pages 1, 6 and 10.

This phrasing also side-steps the issue of whether *page* in your *1st, 6th and 10th page* should be singular or plural.